# Manage 5 User profiles in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I have 5 user profiles: SuperAdmin, FederationPresident, AssociationPresident, ClubPresident, simpleUser

I could grow with time.

So the relations are simple:

A simpleUser belongsTo a club

A club belongsTo an association

An association belongsTo a federation.

Right now, I just have a "type" field in my user table to diferenciate them.

Now, I'm building it, but I write all along my code:

```
if (Auth::user()->isSuperAdmin){
  ...
}elseif (Auth::user()->isPresidentFederation()){
... 
}
```

And I want to refactor it, because it is an hugly way to code it.

Now, first, I managed Roles, and used @can('dothis') in my code, but it is kind of too much in my case and it doesn't fit so well to my use case, so I deleted it.

Everywhere, I have to test what kind of user is logged to know what he is able to perform.

I already use Middlewares to restrict access to unauthorized pages.

For a list of user, a SuperAdmin can see all users, a FederationPresident can see all user of his federation, an AssociationPresident can see all user of his association, etc.

So, I manage it like that:

```
$associations = Association::with('federation.country')
        ->whereHas('federation', function ($query) {
            if (!Auth::user()->isSuperAdmin()) {
                $query->where('president_id', Auth::user()->id);
            }
        })->get();
```

But in the case I would do it for a list of clubs, query would grow, because I would need to check what kind of user is logged.

All those "if" in my code are a bit annoying, as they will be everywhere...

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Whenever I need to filter something by roles, I go for global scopes. I would suggest You, to use it too.

Comment: tx for the tip, I never used it... Now, I'll  figure out how should I use it!

Comment: I don't find a way to use global scopes in this case, can you provide me an quick example???

Comment: I would suggest using this plugin for this purpose. https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust